# How to find Hue value of an Image and use it to apply on other images of similar kind?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm trying to replace color of an object in an image. Suppose if I want to replace the color in the below image object  to the color in the below image object

I change this color using CAD tool, I want to achieve this using python code
I'm replacing HUE color of an Image as below code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread(r"C:\Research\Replace_colors\Bright\Test\b2\img_1_2_pid_13_group_18_P50_A174.png")

# convert img to hsv
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
h = hsv[:,:,0]
s = hsv[:,:,1]
v = hsv[:,:,2]

# shift the hue
# cv2 will clip automatically to avoid color wrap-around
huechange = 10   # 0 is no change; 0<=huechange<=180
hnew = cv2.add(h, huechange)

# combine new hue with s and v
hsvnew = cv2.merge([hnew,s,v])

# convert from HSV to BGR
result = cv2.cvtColor(hsvnew, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)

# save result
cv2.imwrite('result.png', result)
```

I was able to get color close to my required color but not exact color as I wanted

How can I change HUE value so I can replace color exactly ??

Any help or suggestion on this will be very helpful

Comment: You likely need to change saturation and value as well as hue.

Comment: Ok, How can I do that ? can you show me in the code for above sample image?

Comment: why is that picture turning green?

Comment: You need to know the HSV values for the current image and then your desired HSV values. Then modify the HSV channels to shift the colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you are using the right value for huechange and you don't need to change the value channel? When I use a color picker on the large flat part to the top right I get the following HSV values:

Original: (51, 100%, 56.1%)

Modified: (70, 100%, 56.1%)

Desired: (60, 100%, 28.2%)

Comment: ya, I'm not using right value of HUE channel , I used online hue changer to get the above value, How can I modify my code to pass the values which you obtained from color picker?